# Center and fit svg elements inside parent viewbox

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vuejs2

I have two nested svg elements, one outer `<svg>` with a with a dynamic view box (changed by panning and zooming) and an inner element `<g>` where I can put any number of svg elements. On one of my pages I want to show some personal information, and an svg family tree. I'm trying to automatically center and fit this family tree inside the svg window. First I thought I would just iterate through all my elements and get their position to find the min/max coordinates, but a much more efficient way would be to calculate the trees bounding box, the bounding box of the `<g>` element, in the outer svg's view box coordinates.

Now I've tried a few solutions. Just getting a bounding box using `getBBox()` on the inner element returns a bounding box with seemingly correct width and height, but weird x and y. I don't seem to fully understand what `getBBox` does. I also tried using `inner.getBoundingClientRect()` and transforming it to containers coordinates, but end up with the exact same bouding box as returned by `getBBox()`! I hope you can help me. Here's my vue component.

```
<template>
  <div id="svg-container" class="svg-container">
    <svg id="svg-canvas-outer" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
      <svg id="svg-canvas-inner" :viewBox="viewBox">
        <g id="svg-content">
          <slot></slot> <!-- <--family tree -->
        </g>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'SvgContainer',
    props: {
      width: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1000,
      },
      height: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1000,
      },
      margin: {
        type: Number,
        default: 50,
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showControls: false,
        controlsWidthBase: 60,
        controlsHeightBase: 120,
        viewBoxWidth: this.width,
        viewBoxHeight: this.height,
        viewBoxScale: 1.0,
        viewBoxX: 0,
        viewBoxY: 0,
        startPoint: null,
        endPanX: 0,
        endPanY: 0,
        currentlyPanning: false,
        innerSvgElement: undefined,
        mousePos: '',
        mouseViewportPos: '',
        bbox: '',
      };
    },
    computed: {
      viewBox() {
        return `${this.viewBoxX} ${this.viewBoxY} ${this.scaledViewBoxWidth} ${this.scaledViewBoxHeight}`;
      },
      viewBoxPretty() {
        return `${this.viewBoxX.toFixed(2)} ${this.viewBoxY.toFixed(2)} ${this.scaledViewBoxWidth.toFixed(2)} ${this.scaledViewBoxHeight.toFixed(2)}`;
      },
      scaledViewBoxWidth() {
        return this.viewBoxWidth * this.viewBoxScale;
      },
      scaledViewBoxHeight() {
        return this.viewBoxHeight * this.viewBoxScale;
      },
    },
    methods: {
      zoomIn() {
        const scaleFactor = this.viewBoxScale * 0.8;
        this.$_SvgContainer_zoom(scaleFactor);
      },
      zoomOut() {
        const scaleFactor = this.viewBoxScale / 0.8;
        this.$_SvgContainer_zoom(scaleFactor);
      },
      $_SvgContainer_zoom(newScale) {
        const oldWidth = this.scaledViewBoxWidth;
        const oldHeight = this.scaledViewBoxHeight;
        this.viewBoxScale = newScale;
        const newWidth = this.scaledViewBoxWidth;
        const newHeight = this.scaledViewBoxHeight;
        this.panX((newWidth - oldWidth) / 2);
        this.panY((newHeight - oldHeight) / 2);
      },
      sceneBoundingBox() {
        const outer = document.getElementById('svg-canvas-outer');
        const inner = document.getElementById('svg-content');
        const {x: bx, y: by, bottom: bb, right: br} = inner.getBoundingClientRect();
        const pXY = outer.createSVGPoint();
        const pBR = outer.createSVGPoint();
        pXY.x = bx;
        pXY.y = by;
        pBR.x = br;
        pBR.y = bb;
        const inverseCTM = outer.getScreenCTM().inverse();
        const {x, y} = pXY.matrixTransform(inverseCTM);
        const {x: r, y: b} = pBR.matrixTransform(inverseCTM);
        const bbox = inner.getBBox();  // <-- same result as below :(
        return {x: x, y: y, width: (r - x), height: (b - y)};
      },
      centerAndFitContent() {
        const {x: boundingX, y: boundingY, width, height} = this.sceneBoundingBox();

        // Pan svg container to fit
        const boundingCenterX = boundingX + (width / 2);
        const boundingCenterY = boundingY + (height / 2);
        const sceneCenterX = this.scaledViewBoxWidth / 2;
        const sceneCenterY = this.scaledViewBoxHeight / 2;
        this.panX(sceneCenterX - boundingCenterX);
        this.panY(sceneCenterY - boundingCenterY);

        // Zoom svg container to fit
        const widthWithMargin = width + this.margin * 2;
        const heightWithMargin = height + this.margin * 2;
        while (widthWithMargin > this.scaledViewBoxWidth || heightWithMargin > this.scaledViewBoxHeight) {
          this.zoomOut();
        }
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.centerAndFitContent();
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I suggest to use d3 for zooming/panning purposes and abandon nested svg structure

Comment: Well, my panning and zooming works well, just not finding the position of this tree...